# preg_match_all google latitude and longitude

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got the following string:

```
a:3:{s:3:"lat";s:17:"49.21103723075132";s:3:"lng";s:18:"22.330280542373657";s:4:"zoom";s:2:"17";}
```

And I want to get from it this:

```
49.21103723075132
```

and

```
22.330280542373657
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex. It's serialized string. deserialize it:

```
$str = 'a:3:{s:3:"lat";s:17:"49.21103723075132";s:3:"lng";s:18:"22.330280542373657";s:4:"zoom";s:2:"17";}';
$deserialized = unserialize($str);
var_dump($deserialized);
```

output is:

```
array(3) {
  ["lat"]=>
  string(17) "49.21103723075132"
  ["lng"]=>
  string(18) "22.330280542373657"
  ["zoom"]=>
  string(2) "17"
}
```

So you can access it as elements of array: `$deserialized['lat']`, `$deserialized['lng']`